# on the server is not added "isAdmin" : true,

Tags: mongodb

I want to ask you for help.

App running on localhost great. 
but on the server is not added **"isAdmin" : true,** to the mongoDB. When you add admin.

Why? Where is the problem ?

localhost:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("57b174723e755f5dfe36d8b0"),
"salt" : "63855ff664682ad1e8ed77ded97ca5b92da472e9f0f7d68dcb058f35e71d38a4",
"hash" : "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",
"username" : "mail@gmail.com",
"displayName" : "Admin",
"isAdmin" : true,
"__v" : 0
}
```

server:

```
  {
"_id" : ObjectId("57b174723e755f5dfe36d8b0"),
"salt" : "63855ff664682ad1e8ed77ded97ca5b92da472e9f0f7d68dcb058f35e71d38a4",
"hash" : "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",
"username" : "mail@gmail.com",
"displayName" : "Admin",
"__v" : 0
   }
```

**Model**

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var User = new Schema({
username: String,
password: String,
displayName: String,
isAdmin: Boolean
}, {
toObject: { virtuals: true },
toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});

User.virtual("token").set(function(token) {
this._token = token;
}).get(function() { return this._token; });

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", User);
```

**RegisterController**

```
     app.controller("RegisterController",
[
"$scope", "$location", "Account", "Session", 
function($scope, $location, account, session) {

    $scope.registerForm = {
        name: undefined,
        email: undefined,
        password: undefined,
        confirmPassword: undefined,
        errorMessage: undefined
    };

    $scope.register = function() {
        account.register($scope.registerForm.name, $scope.registerForm.email, $scope.registerForm.password, $scope.registerForm.confirmPassword)
            .then(function(res) {
                session.setUserData(res);
                $location.path("/");
            }, function(response) {
                $scope.registerForm.errorMessage = response.message;
            });
    };
}
]);
```

**Service session**

```
app.factory("Session", ["$http", function ($http) {
return {
    getToken: function() {
        var value = sessionStorage.getItem("token");

        if (value) return value;

        return undefined;
    },
    getEmail: function() {
        var value = sessionStorage.getItem("email");

        if (value) return value;

        return undefined;
    },
    getIsAdmin: function() {
        var value = sessionStorage.getItem("isAdmin");

        if (value) return value == "true";

        return undefined;
    },
    setUserData: function(user) {
        sessionStorage.setItem("token", user.token);
        sessionStorage.setItem("email", user.username);

        $http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + user.token;

        if (user.isAdmin) {
            sessionStorage.setItem("isAdmin", "true");
        }
    },
    clear: function() {
        sessionStorage.clear();

        $http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = undefined;            
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: How are you adding records to the database?

Comment: I use a passport -local- mongoose . I added the code above.